# ¿Porque cuando recargo la pagina me sale el 404 en angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Soy nuevo en **AngularJS** y estoy aprendiendo como hacer enrutamiento. Logré hacer que funcionara correctamente el ruteo de varias vistas en una misma pagina sin tener que recargar la página principal, todo bien hasta ahí.

Mi problema ya se presenta es cuando veo que la URL tiene unos símbolos (estos exactamente #!) cuando navega entre las diferente paginas de la siguiente manera:

```
http://localhost:8080/Proyectos/AngularJS/Routing/#!/Vista1
```

Encontré que para quitarlos debo usar la funcion `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` y la etiqueta `base` de html para poder quitar esos símbolos de la URL y que quedara más limpia, lo hice y funcionó.

El problema es que si intento recargar la página en la que estoy, como por ejemplo esta `http://localhost:8080/Proyectos/AngularJS/Routing/Vista1` me dice

> "Objeto no encontrado Error 404"

Si recargo en la raíz, es decir asi: `http://localhost:8080/Proyectos/AngularJS/Routing/` si funciona normal.

Quisiera saber, ¿A qué se debe esto? y ¿Qué puedo hacer para que pueda recargar la página no importando la página en la que me encuentre?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/ProyectosCristian/AngularJS/Routing/">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular-route.js"></script>

    <title>Routing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cont" ng-app="app">
        <div class="menu">
            <menu></menu>
        </div>
        <div class="views" ng-view></div>
        <div ng-controller="control"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'components/home.html'
            })  
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'components/home.html'
            })      
            .when('/seccion1', {
                templateUrl: 'components/seccion1.html'
            })
            .when('/seccion2',{
                templateUrl: 'components/seccion2.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });         
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: true
            }).hashPrefix(['!']);
        }]);

        app.directive('menu', function(){
            return{
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'components/menu.html'
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo tengo funcionando

Simplemente agregando un archivo `.htaccess` en la raíz

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, proba con este código, en vez de `<base href="/ProyectosCristian/AngularJS/Routing/">` 

escribe `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>
        <head>             
            <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">   
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="components/angular-route.js"></script>

            <title>Routing</title>
       </head>
```

Comment: Si te funciona me avisas!!!

Comment: **No, no me funcionó**, pero gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Gracias por intentarlo, yo justamente lo estaba investigando cuando te comente y ese codigo no lo habia probado, pero estas en lo correcto... No funciona :( .... Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: No he podido :(